# Need to add dropdown menu to magento 2 checkout page city field

Tags: magento2

**I Need to Add Dropdown Menu Checkout Page City Field In magento 2**

```
1. Could you tell me the file path of checkpout page phtml file.

2. Also need to replace postal code according to city option.
```

Comment: You can refer this link for same.
https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: i have used this plugin. but it didn't work. can i have a proper installation guid for this extension.

Comment: also please mention what is the file path that i need to extract the whole plugin

Answer (score 0):

below path for the checkout page in magento2

app/design/frontend/default interface folder/default theme folder/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

Comment: Thank you! for the response. 

but in my case there is no default.phtml in that path.